# Shared Field Name Between Entity Types?

Tags: 8, configuration

I have always separated my field names by entity. e.g.

`field_paragraph_h2` or `field_content_h2`,

but when you look at config, fields are designated by their entity type as well.

`field.field.paragraph.paragraph_type.field_paragraph_h2` or `field.field.node.content_type.field_content_h2`

Am I safe using just `field_h2` for both entity type field names, or are there instances with Drupal where this may be problematic?

e.g.

`field.field.paragraph.paragraph_type.field_h2` or `field.field.node.content_type.field_h2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are safe to use the same name. The fields are unique for each entity type, even when they have the same name.

They have their own field storage configuration, instances and will be stored to dedicated database tables per entity type.

Comment: *edit: One reason that got me wondering is that in `field.html.twig`, for example, `{{ field_name }}` returns only the field machine name. This is fine because it is the theming layer, my concerns were for preprocessing where php errors/collisions could occur.